# Bouncy Castle AES-256 Decryption Failed

Tags: java, aes, bouncycastle

I am getting this exception while decoding encoded string. For few cases it is working fine but if I insert a large Cipher code for decryption It is giving me Exception as follows:

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(Unknown Source)   
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown 
Source)
```

With following code..

```
public byte[] encryptAES256(byte[] input, byte[] key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    assert key.length == 32;
    CipherParameters cipherParameters = new KeyParameter(key);
    BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();
    BlockCipherPadding blockCipherPadding = new PKCS7Padding();
    BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, blockCipherPadding);
    return encrypt(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters);
}

public byte[] decryptAES256(byte[] input, byte[] key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    assert key.length == 32;
    CipherParameters cipherParameters = new KeyParameter(key);
    BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();
    BlockCipherPadding blockCipherPadding = new PKCS7Padding();
    BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, blockCipherPadding);
    return decrypt(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters);
}

public byte[] process(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, CipherParameters cipherParameters, boolean forEncryption) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    bufferedBlockCipher.init(forEncryption, cipherParameters);
    byte[] rv = new byte[bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int tam = bufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, rv, 0);
    try {
        bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(rv, tam);
        return rv;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return rv; 
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, 
    CipherParameters cipherParameters) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    boolean forEncryption = false;
    return process(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters, forEncryption);
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out why I am getting this exception?

Comment: You don't seem to have a method called `encrypt`.

Comment: **encrypt** method is same as decrypt except boolean value will be true in case of encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you ignore a return value it should give you pause. You are ignoring the return value of `bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(rv, tam)` in your `process` method. I believe that, in your code, that will only cause a problem during a decryption operation. Note that `bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(input.length)` will return a value that is a **minimum** length, not necessarily an exact length. In other words, it may be a little too big. The `doFinal` method will give you the actual size of the last block after padding has been removed. You can then return a properly sized array by using something as simple as [`java.util.Arrays.copyOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-byte:A-int-), e.g.

```
int lastBlockLen = bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(rv, tam);
return Arrays.copyOf(rv, tam + lastBlockLen);
```

Comment: I've tried that code but I am getting same error. I am getting error on **doFinal** method.

Comment: @Pushkar: I would need to have more info on what isn't working because it works for me.

Comment: It is not working if I try to decrypt a big cipher text like more than 1000 character in cipher text. It is working if cipher text is like 16 character.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. You'll have to do a little work to produce the **smallest** input that causes your problem, then edit your question to add that information to it.